# Failed leader-election for for existing ISR in Kafka 2.2.0

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 3 node kafka-cluster (broker version 2.2.0) with following config/deployment details:

- Partition count per topic : 3-4 partitions for our application topics. `__consumer_offsets` partitions was determined by Kafka on on its own - `100` partitions
- ReplicationFactor : 2 (including topic : `__consumer_offsets` topic)
- Broker-Ids are : `0, 1` and `2`
- When a node is brought-down corresponding Zookeeper instance also goes down. ie deployment is more as a single appliance running pair of Kafka + ZK per appliance

I am testing single-node outage behaviour and I bring down `broker-id 0` (and corresponding colocated ZK instance)

What I observe is that:
Before bringing down `broker-id 0`, following is the distribution retrieved via `describe-topic CLI` for topic : `__consumer_offsets`. Behaviour is same for our application topics too

[image]

After bringing down `broker-id 0`, same output for same partitions look like below:

[image: *enter image description here*]

Now, the main concern is `Leader: -1"`. 
When there was a valid `ISR broker-id 2` and **also** when `broker-id 2` is leader for certain partitions (eg. Partitions `2, 5, 8` above) and `broker-id 2` was **alive**, why did partitions - `0, 3, 6, 9` not elect `broker-id 2` as leader for those partitions ?

I tried to find if there was a double-fault - ie. more than one broker went down simultaneously. But, could not find any proof for the same in logs of `broker-id 1` and `2`

As mentioned above, I would expect partitions - `0, 3, 6, 9` to have `broker-id 2` as leader when `broker-id 0` went down.

Kindly clarify

- why above expectation is not met
- also please indicate if there are any specific broker-log messages to scan as to why `broker-id 2` was not elected as leader for partitions  `0, 3, 6, 9` in this scenario
- any other scenarios other than single-node outage can cause this
- I have also checked if ZK ensemble is intact and it works fine with just two nodes when one node is brought-down

Comment: how long does this period of time (with no leader) last? also, which broker was cluster leader at the time 0 went down? which machine was zk leader?

Comment: The condition of Leader=-1 is permanent as long as broker-id - 0 is not brought up. Leader of ZK moved to machine corresponding to . Broker-Id 1. Before that ZK leader was machine corresponding to Broker-id 0 (which was brought down). Hence ZK seems intact. Also I checked the live Kafka broker-ids reflected in /brokers/ids after bringing down node-0 and it correctly reflects remaining brokers - 1 and 2

Comment: looking at partition 0, the in-sync replica set is only {0}, meaning that broker {2} will not be appointed leader, as doing so would lose data (if 2 becomes leader than 0 will truncate data if/when it rejoins to match what 2 has). whats your setting for unclean leader election ?.

other partitions (like 1) that were led by zero successfully transferred leadership, so i suspect the ISR set at crash time to be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect the issue is unclean leader election (lack thereof) and a small ISR (in sync replica) set:

partition 0 is leaderless after broker 0 crashed. it also shows 0 as the single (!) member of the ISR set - this means that kafka metadata states broker 0 had unique user data (that was ack'ed to the original producer(s)) thats not found anywhere else. allowing any broker other than 0 to become leader for this partition will result in data loss - if/when 0 rejoins it will truncate its "head" of data to match what the new leader has - thereby dropping this unique data. you need to enable the setting for unclean leader election for that to happen.

partition 1, for example, transitioned over from broker 0 to broker 1, which means a new kafka controller was successfully elected for your cluster after broker 0 went down.

other options you can explore to prevent this situation from happening are increasing min isr on the broker side (along with your overall replication factor, otherwise loss of any broker will render partitions read-only) and/or increasing the acks setting on your producer side

see https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_ha.html for more details on these settings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Actually, I have left the default setting for unclean leader election to be false and producer acks to leader-only. Retained default for avoiding any possible data-loss
 
Only reservation which was keeping us away was to see if we do Rf=3, min-isr = 2 *and* acks=all (if enabled) we would have higher latency on producer-side.

Another thought is - the ZK update by brokers could have got corrupted and whether we can increase `zookeeper.session.timeout.ms` so that partial updates to broker can be avoided  - your thoughts on the same ?

Comment: Another important point which I missed (sorry about that) is that each appliance (or server) runs Kafka + Zookeeper instances. The scenario is about bringing-down single applicance. ie. one instance of Zookeeper and one instance of Kafka is brought-down _together_  .. checked if zookeeper is working fine after single-instance of ensemble brought-down using ZK Cli and it seems to be working without any issues